# Why are there gaps in between my model?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I just started to learn Blender and was following a tutorial on YouTube on making ice-cream. I was almost done with the cream but when I added subdivision modifier my model started having gaps. Please give me some suggestions how to solve it. I am pretty sure I followed the tutorial. Here is the link to the tutorial on Youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvTrZ0soo_Q&list=PLrjIgEdKLivgpCMmFC0_sV60Y_Ftp-WLD&index=2

[image]
[image]

Please tell me if you want more screen shots.

Comment: maybe try to enable the Merge option of the Array modifier?

Answer (score 1):

You missed at least two things while following the tutorial.

1. At 11:15 Steve explains that you have to set the *Array Modifier* to *Fit Curve*. Your screenshot shows you've set it to *Fit Length*.
2. The second thing is, after adding the *Subdivision Surface Modifier* he explains why it doesn't look smooth enough yet and at 12:25 he enables the option *Merge* in the *Array Modifier*.

Maybe these two things might help to make it look right.

Comment: i m grateful for your suggestion but still it dont work do i have some blender setting messed up?

Comment: but i just scraped the whole cream part and started it again and it worked. thx

Comment: Glad it worked now. Actually there might have been something messed up, but that wasn't clear from the screenshot. Maybe a file upload would have helped investigating it further. I just know from following tutorials myself, most of the times when something's not working it's just something I missed.